# Do emulators or Genymotion support ART, the dalvik replacement?

Tags: android, emulation, dalvik, genymotion, android-runtime

[ART](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html) is the next generation of Dalvik.

Is there anyway to emulate it with Android emulators or with [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) ?

Comment: In the 4.4 emulator I fond the option under the developer options. I do not know if it that what you were looking for

Comment: Is Android 4.4 already available with Genymotion?

Comment: @rciovati, not yet, but I hope Daniel Fagues will see this and answer directly and give an ETA.

Comment: I just tried to switch the Dalvik to ART on the Emulator,but it doesnt enter the system now 2 hours later. Isn't it work on the emulator?

Comment: It doesn't work on 4.4 emulators up to now.

Comment: See this other question which has a quite useful answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995275/impossible-to-use-art-on-android-emulator

Comment: @Uwe Post, I don't think this can be related to GenyMotion ART support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch between `Dalvik` and `ART`, under `Settings -> Developer options -> Select Runtime`

---- Update

The above doesn't work, the emulator doesn't boot.

-- Update 2

[android ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61999)

-- Update 3

With the latest GenyMotion (4.4.2), switching to ART works !!

The device can't shutdown properly to reboot but, close its window, restart a VM, it will reboot using ART. Thanks Geny Mobile !!

Comment: With GenyMotion and emulators ? It looks like it takes several days to boot the emulator that way...if it works

Comment: only with the android emulator. I agree on the second part

Comment: Could you make it boot ?

Comment: I am waiting for it to book

Comment: The attempt of my friend to boot Android emulator with Art didn't succeed after more than 3 days of boot... Could you make it work @blackbelt ?

Comment: Let's hope we get a better support (or a newer phone ?).

Comment: The new nexus 5, please Santa Claus, please