# Impossible to use ART on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, art-runtime

I just wanted to try ART of android 4.4 on my emulator. 
What I did was create an emulator with selecting device as "Nexus 7" and target as "Android 4.4" and RAM "512". Then I started emulator and it loaded.
Then I went to Developer Options and selected runtime as ART.
After that setting emulator started to reboot and kept on booting screen for a long time(around 1hr) and couldn't finish launching.

Can anybody explain me the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the emulator image. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61999

You can download a modified image from http://pan.baidu.com/s/1iUQaI

Comment: That modified image link is broken. :(